# Appending rows to CSV with pandas - duplicating headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have it set to "append" but when it's pulling the info from the table, it's throwing the header in for every record.  i've read multiple threads on here but haven't found anything that worked. here are 4 of the urls i'm using and the code that i have.

http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057804&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors
http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057805&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors
http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057806&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors
http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057807&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

contents = []
with open('WV_urls.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

    for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
        page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
        df, header = pd.read_html(page)
        df.to_csv('WV_Licenses_Daily.csv', index=False, header=None, mode='a')
```

However, if i use just 2 urls by themselves, it prints the header and appends the second file.

```
calls_df, header = pd.read_html('http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057728&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors', header=0)
calls_df1, header = pd.read_html('http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057729&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors', header=0)

calls_df.to_csv('WV_Licenses_Daily.csv', index=False, header=None, mode='w')
calls_df1.to_csv('WV_Licenses_Daily.csv', index=False, header=None, mode='a')
```

Comment: What if you use `header=False` rather than `header=None`

Comment: no dice.  does the same thing. If i use two urls seperately, without calling them from a list, it works just fine.  I've updated the initial question to show you what i'm talking about.

Comment: Your "separate calls" example uses a different methodology to read the HTML file - `pd.read_html(url)` rather than `pd.read_html(urlopen(url).read())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You missed the header argument in the above code that's why it is throwing header in every file append.
   `df, header = pd.read_html(page)`
2. If you put **header** as **0** then it will give the results as you want but still you miss the top header as you default appending to empty file which don't has any data

```
    import csv
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import pandas as pd

    contents = []
    with open('WV_urls.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
        urls = csv.reader(csvf)
        for url in urls:
            contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents
        for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
            page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
            df, header = pd.read_html(page,header=0)
            df.to_csv('WV_Licenses_Daily.csv', index=False, header=None, mode='a')
```

3. You can create a empty data frame with required columns. After that you can append the data frames to it.

```
    import csv
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import pandas as pd

    contents = []
    df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['WV Number', 'Company', 'DBA', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip','County', 'Phone', 'Classification*', 'Expires']) #initialize the data frame with columns
    with open('WV_urls.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
        urls = csv.reader(csvf)
        for url in urls:
            contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents
        for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
            page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
            df1, header = pd.read_html(page,header=0)#reading with header
            df=df.append(df1) # append to dataframe

    df.to_csv('WV_Licenses_Daily.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: awesome!  I tried everything with header and mode.  except for that. :) Thanks for the help

Comment: i do have a quick question.  Say i want to break the loop if it hits a page that only has the header but no content.  I figure i can us a break statement, but not sure exactly how i would go about it.  Any suggestions?!

Comment: At that time the data frame will be empty. You can check whether the data frame is empty or not if it is empty then you can break the loop.